# Protocol error in TDS stream - error

Tags: c#, sql-server, tcp, connection-string, network-protocols

We have two servers. An application server and a SQL server.

When running this simple program from the application server:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd;
            OleDbConnection cnn;
            string connectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=***;Password=***;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=MCS_BATCH;Data Source=CD6S01;Initial File Name=;";
            string sql = "EXEC [msp].[MasterMSP] @BTYPE = N'B_PVM_KNN', @AC_KEY = NULL, @RUN_TS = '2014-05-02 17:29:31.1400555', @CHUNK_ID = 8794";

            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("MasterMSP_output.txt");

            cnn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cnn);
                try
                {

                    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    int numberOfFields = reader.VisibleFieldCount;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < (numberOfFields - 1); i++)
                        {
                            file.Write(reader[i].ToString());
                        }
                        file.WriteLine("");
                    }
                    file.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    file.Write("Execption ex at : {0}", System.DateTime.Now);
                    file.Write(ex.Message.ToString());

                    Console.WriteLine("Exception ex time is : {0}", System.DateTime.Now);
                    throw;
                }

                cmd.Dispose();
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exx)
            {
                file.Write("Execption exx at : {0}", System.DateTime.Now);
                file.Write(exx.Message.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Exception exx time is : {0}", System.DateTime.Now);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

We get - after some time - a "Protocol error in TDS stream" error:

[image: Protocol error in TDS stram]

We ran a network trace, and we can see that the "TCP Window size" is decreasing after 10 mins and then it's sending a TCP Window size = 0 (close window). 
This means that the SQL server can't send more data until it has gotten a update window size, bigger than 0, from the application server.(right?):

[image: Networktrace]

The SQL server is trying to send 1 byte keepalive, but the application server is never responding. (The problem is that the application server never raise TCP Windows Size again. At the end the application server is terminating the session.)

We except that it's the application server fault and it could be that the networks buffer is not being empty(flushed) anymore. The only thing the TCP stack can do is to close the TCP Windows Size until the application again empties the buffer - but it never does that.

Any hints, ideas on what the issue can be? 
The problem actually came up in 3rd party program. This program is calling a stored procedure on the SQL server. So I just tried to reproduce the logic in a C# program and was able to reproduce the error.

Any help, ideas or comments are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What program are the screenshots from?

Comment: "CMD" and "Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the connectionstring fixed the error: **MARS Connection=True**

[Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345109%28d=printer,v=sql.90%29.aspx)